# How can I prevent RStudio's autocomplete behavior from generating errors inside of function arguments?

Tags: r, autocomplete, rstudio

I just updated RStudio on my Mac to version 2023.03.0+386, and certain autocomplete functionality I used to use extensively seems to have changed.  Specifically, I'll look to select columns for a join in the middle of a pipe stream.  Previously, the autocomplete was fairly intelligent and context-aware and would draw from the names of the table I was trying to join from.  Now, attempting to autocomplete generates the error: `Error in context[[1L]] : subscript out of bounds`.  Out of habit, I'll provide a reprex, although since that fails to reproduce the error, I will attach a screenshot as well.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

set.seed(42)
df1 <- data.frame(
  id = 1:10,
  x = runif(10),
  y = sample(letters[1:10])
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  id = 3:7,
  z = rnorm(5)
)

df2 %>% 
  left_join({ # With cursor in these curly brackest, hit tab to autocomplete.
    df1 %>% 
      select(id, x)
  })
#> Joining, by = "id"
#>   id          z         x
#> 1  3  2.2866454 0.2861395
#> 2  4 -1.3888607 0.8304476
#> 3  5 -0.2787888 0.6417455
#> 4  6 -0.1333213 0.5190959
#> 5  7  0.6359504 0.7365883
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Similarly, completing or even executing snippets inside of a function call generates the same error. Example `read.csv(`*tries to type "Downloads" snippet which produces the path to my downloads folder*`)`.

What is happening now that wasn't previously?

More importantly (to me), can I either

- change some setting to revert to the previous behavior? or
- use some fancy new join function I haven't learned about yet which will yield behavior similarly useful to the previous?

I'm grateful for any explanation or help available.

[image: screenshot showing error]

Comment: I assume this is also you with the cross-post to a different forum: https://community.rstudio.com/t/latest-rstudio-update-has-changed-autocomplete-behavior-seeking-help-understanding/162649. What version of R are you running (not RStudio)? You can check by running `R.version.string` in the R console.

Comment: @MrFlick, I'm running R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31), which I now see is not current.  I'll update R and report back.  Regarding the cross-post, you are correct.  I figured the chief audience should be there, so I tried there first even though I know that there tends to be more activity here.

Comment: @MrFlick, I've upgraded to R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15) and the new behavior described above persists.

Comment: My guess is there is not an RStudio setting you can change. I would suggest [downgrading your RStudio to meet your needs](https://docs.posit.co/previous-versions/) while continuing to engage with the RStudio forums/team to advocate for your desires.

Comment: What's the output of `traceback()` right after this error? (just saw that [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12145))

Comment: Getting same results now on Windows.

Comment: I'm having basically the same problem, although I wasn't able to even figure out that it was an autocomplete problem. Sometimes -- not sure when -- when using a package I wrote, I will suddenly get dozens of these error messages one right after another before I've even hit return while typing a command into the console. If anyone can make it stop, I'm very interested, too!